Bounding the dimension of $H^1(G, V\otimes V^{\vee})$
Let $G_S$ denote the Galois group of the maximal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ unramified away from a finite set of primes, $S$. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional,  $G_S$-representation over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (assume $p\in S$).
What is the best bound known in the literature for the dimension of the $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space $H^1(G_S, V\otimes V^{\vee})$?
Edit: originally I asked about the case where $V$ is a trivial representation, in which case $H^1$ is the same as $\text{Hom}$, and the dimension is the same as the number of $\mathbb{Q}$-extensions of degree $p$, unramified outside $S$ multiplied by $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p}(V)^2$.

trivial? That would reduce to $H^1(G_S, \mathbb{F}_p) = \operatorname{Hom}(G_S,\mathbb{F}_p)$ which counts the degree $p$ Galois extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ unramified outside $S$.
